# Why should I remove the form tag from the master page when using bootstrap & ASP.Net webformds

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, webforms

In a [couple](http://www.mytecbits.com/microsoft/dot-net/bootstrap-3-0-0-with-asp-net-web-forms) [Tutorials](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/815916/How-To-Create-an-Asp-Net-Web-Forms-Application-usi) that have been suggested on this site on integrating bootstrap with ASP.Net Web Forms, they suggest that the form tag be removed from the master page. Here is one [tutorial](http://geekswithblogs.net/JeremyMorgan/archive/2012/09/18/how-to-use-twitter-bootstrap-on-an-asp.net-website.aspx) where they leave in the form tag:

On the asp.net site where it describes [master pages](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/master-pages/creating-a-site-wide-layout-using-master-pages-cs), it mentions why there is a form tag in the master page:

> A Web Form (the `<form runat="server">`) - because all ASP.NET pages typically have a Web Form - and because the master page may include Web controls that must appear within a Web Form - be sure to add the Web Form to your master page (rather than adding a Web Form to each content page).

A lot of the asp controls I use in the master page and content pages require a parent form tag, therefore it would be cumbersome to remove this parent form tag on my master page.

Why is it necessary to remove the form tag from the master page when adding bootstrap to the site?  Does bootstrap not work properly when its inside of a form tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap works fine with the form tag in the master page.  Just keep in mind that you are probably going to have to tweak/override styles a little bit here and there.  For the most part it is very minor though.  I have not found any compelling reason to remove the form tag from the master page.